# How to multiply specific columns of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I'm trying to multiply certain columns in my pandas dataframe by 100. Specifically those columns that are in the middle of the df.

Here is the code I'm trying to use in my Jupyter Notebook:

```
quality = quality[['Question','Excellent','Above average','Average','Below the average','Very poor','Total']]

quality['Excellent','Above average','Average','Below the average','Very poor'] = quality['Excellent','Above average','Average','Below the average','Very poor']*100

quality
```

I expect the output should be 11.82% from 0.1182 for a cell.

The output I get is the following:

> KeyError: ('Excellent', 'Above average', 'Average', 'Below the average', 'Very poor')

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double square brackets to select multiple columns. Then you can shorten your code a bit:

```
quality[['Excellent','Above average','Average','Below the average','Very poor']] *= 100
```

Comment: Hello Tom, thanks for your answer but I have a question: in my df I have 2 columns that are strings and I want to maintain order so if I create a df from the columns above I will lose the order I have right?

Comment: @AngeloMerkel You're welcome. Feel free to select it as your accepted answer. You can reorder the dataframes after this in any order you like, for example: `df= df[['Very Poor,'Below the average','Average','Above average','Excellent'']]`